# Phase space orbit for a projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, phase-space

After playing around with drawing the phase space orbit for a harmonic oscillator I started wondering about the case for a free falling object. So the equations of motion are:

$$
P = P_0 + mgt
$$ 
and
$$ 
q = q_o + \frac{P_o}{m}t + \frac{1}{2}gt^2.
$$

So my problem here is that I am not clear on how to solve for the trajectory. that is, obtain the momentum as a function of position, $P=P(q)$.
Could someone put me on the right direction?
Tried putting solving for the time in terms of the other two quantities, but I did not seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting to eliminate time is the right idea. Re-arrange the first equation to give:

$$t=\frac{P-P_{0}}{mg}$$

Insert that into the second equation:

$$q=q_{0}+\frac{P_0}{m}\left(\frac{P-P_{0}}{mg}\right)+\frac{1}{2}g\left(\frac{P-P_{0}}{mg}\right)^{2}$$

Then expand the brackets, cancel out what you can, and rearrange into the form that you want. Since you're doing this for fun, I'll not give you the final result.